# overflow scroll issue in android 2.x

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, popup

I have designed android phonegap app using jquery mobile.I need to show the popup and i setted the height for jquery mobile popup.I have given Overflow:scroll in css and popup content is getting scrolled in android 4.0,but its not scrolled in android 2.2.

Here is my code

```
<div align="center">
 <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Pop Up</a>
</div>  
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic" data-dismissable="false" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="c" >
  <p id="popup_content">PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the platforms you care about.Easily create apps using the web technologies you know and love: HTML, CSS and JavaScript.From first-timers to long-time veterans, we’ve got your dev needs covered. The developer portal is the place to find guides, documentation and tutorials.This guide describes how to set up your development environment for Cordova and run a sample application.</p>
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

.ui-popup {
    position: relative;
    height:100px;
        overflow:scroll;
}

Please Kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this problem while developing a phonegap app for android. Basically, overflow: scroll doesn't work in android 2.2; see these bug reports:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118

 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2911

I solved the problem by using a javascript solution: https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

Hope this helps!